# A finite normal subgroup is a subset of the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

> Let $G$ be a group of odd order and $N$ a normal subgroup of order 17. Prove that $N\subset Z(G)=\{z\in G:  \forall_{g\in G}: gzg^{-1}=z\}$.

I was given the hint to look at what $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ looks like, and then apply the fact that you have a group homomorphism $f:G\to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ with $f(g)=\phi_g|_N$, with $\phi_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$, restricted to $N$.

I'm not sure about my following approach, because it worked for me only using the second hint. This makes me doubt the correctness as hints are usually not given for no reason; what I have:

---

$\#N=17\implies N$ is cyclic and thus abelian. We then have $f(n)=\phi_n|_N=id_N$ for all $n\in N$. After all: $\phi_n|_N(x)=nxn^{-1}=nn^{-1}x=x$ for all $x\in N$. From this it follows that $N\subset\ker(f)$.

Now: $g\in \ker(f) \iff \phi_g|_N=id_N \iff$ $\forall_{n\in N}:\phi_g|_N(n)=n \iff \forall_{n\in N}: gng^{-1}=n \iff g\in Z(N)\subset Z(G)$.

So: $N\subset \ker(f)=Z(N)\subset Z(G)$ so that $N\subset Z(G)$.

**This is where my mistake was**: $Z(N)\not\subset Z(G)$.

---

Does anyone have any tips using my approach? Or is it not useful to look at the kernel of this homomorphism? What about the first hint? I'm not sure what else to say about $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ other than finding what it is isomorphic to (Maybe something like $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$?)

Comment: Why $Z(N) \subset Z(G)$?

Comment: @KennyLau I actually just looked at how I wrote it down and I think I see the mistake; I said $Z(N)=\{z\in N: gzg^{-1}=g\}$ for all $g\in G$ but that of course must be $nzn^{-1}$ for all $n\in N$ so they're not actually subsets.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N = \langle n \rangle$. We need to show that $gng^{-1} = n$ for all $g \in G$, i.e. $f(g) = \operatorname{id}_N$.

Now, note that $\operatorname{ord}(f(g)) \mid 16$, as $|\operatorname{Aut}(N)| = |\Bbb Z/16\Bbb Z| = 16$.

Also, since $f$ is a homomorphism, $\operatorname{ord}(f(g)) \mid \operatorname{ord}(g)$.

By Lagrange theorem, $\operatorname{ord}(g) \mid G$.

But $G$ is odd, so $\operatorname{ord}(g)$ is odd, so $\operatorname{ord}(f(g))$ is odd, so $\operatorname{ord}(f(g)) = 1$, so $f(g) = \operatorname{id}_N$ as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's a couple of things I'm not completely getting;

- I'm not familiar with the Lagrange theorem, what is it about in general?

- How do you know $\operatorname{Aut} (N) \cong \mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$?

- How does it follow that $\#f(g)=1 \implies f(g)=id_N$?

Comment: 1. [Lagrange theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) states that the size of a subgroup divides the order of a group (how are you doing centralizers if Lagrange theorem hasn't been taught?) 2. $N$ is cyclic, so see [this](http://planetmath.org/automorphismgroupofacyclicgroup). 3. The order of $f(g)$ is by definition the least positive integer $r$ such that $f(g)^r = e$, where $e = \operatorname{id}_N$ is the identity of the group. Here, $r = 1$, so $f(g) = e$.

Comment: Thank you for your references. I'm only a first-years mathematics student so often I find it hard to find sources to answer my questions without involving a lot of complex math. And actually, I might've had that theorem once but maybe it wasn't named

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on $aut(N)\cong \mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$ in this case? I understand the case with $\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know how to use that when you don't have 'numbers' and 'primes' in $N$ as it is an arbitrary group with arbitrary operations

Comment: [every group of prime order is cyclic](http://planetmath.org/proofthateverygroupofprimeorderiscyclic)

Comment: I know that, but how does that translate to $aut(n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Marc $N \cong \Bbb Z/17\Bbb Z$, so $\operatorname{Aut}(N) \cong \Bbb Z/16\Bbb Z$. For this purpose, it suffices to know that its cardinality is $16$, which can be seen by the fact that every number $r$ coprime to $17$ gives an automorphism of $\Bbb Z/17\Bbb Z$ sending $x$ to $rx$.

Comment: I discussed with some friends and I can see how it works now. One last question then; we want to show that $gng^{-1}=n$ for all $g\in G$, cause then you know that $n\in Z(G)$. How does this translate to $f(g)=id_N$ for all $g\in G$? If the latter is true, wouldn't $\ker f=G=N=Z(N)=Z(G)$? Since for any $g$, $f(g)=id_N$ so $g\in \ker f$

Comment: 1. Because $f(g)(n^k) = gn^kg^{-1} = (gng^{-1})^k = n^k$ 2. $\ker f = G = Z(N) = Z(G) \ne N$

Comment: But if this holds for all $g\in G$, why isn't $\ker f = G$?

Comment: $\ker f = G$ is correct.

Comment: $Z(N)\subset N$ per definition. Suppose $x\in N$, then $nxn^{-1}=x$ for all $n\in N$ because $N$ is abelian. So, $x\in Z(N)$. Thus $N\subset Z(N) \implies Z(N)=N$. Where does this go wrong?

Comment: You're confusing the centre and the centralizer. $Z(N) \subseteq N$ indeed, but we don't care about $Z(N)$. It's $C(N;G)$ that we care about.

Comment: $Z(N) = \{z\in N: nzn^{1}=z\}$ for all $n\in N$? Is that incorrect?